# IntelliJ Align arguments to opening parenthesis?

Tags: intellij-idea, arguments, indentation, code-formatting

When I split arguments onto multiple lines in IntelliJ, it puts the argument at a slight indent from the line above. For example:

```
ClassName.staticMethod(argument1,
    argument2,
    argument3);
```

Quick, what are the arguments above? Okay, that's easy because of the example names I chose, but how about below? Which arguments are going to `staticMethod` below?

```
ClassName.staticMethod(this.instanceMethod(argument1,
    argument2),
    argument3);
```

`staticMethod` is taking the results of a call to `instanceMethod` and `argment3`, but with IntelliJ's default formatting, at a glance you'd completely miss the fact that `argument2` is an argument for `instanceMethod`, not `staticMethod`.

This is a freaking terrible default behavior. How can I get it to properly line arguments up, as in the modified examples below?

```
ClassName.staticMethod(argument1,
                       argument2,
                       argument3);

ClassName.staticMethod(this.instanceMethod(argument1,
                                           argument2),
                       argument3);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Settings | Editor | Code Style | Java | Wrapping and Braces | Method call arguments | [x] Align when multiline

Comment: Great, thanks! IntelliJ has far too many settings (and far too many of them have the incorrect defaults).